# How to properly call methods with no input arguments

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qtopcua

The Qt Documentation provides the method

```
bool QOpcUaNode::callMethod(const QString &methodNodeId, const QVector<QOpcUa::TypedVariant> &args = QVector<QOpcUa::TypedVariant>())
```

for calling methods on the Opc Ua Server. Regarding this Method I have 2 Questions:

1. What exactly is methodNodeId ? I imagine it is the Id of the Node I want to call, but if this is the case, why would the function not be static instead ?
2. How to call methods with 0 input arguments? trying to call `myNode->callMethod(methodNodeId)` without specifiying further arguments still returns `BadTooManyArguments`, but there is really not other way I could see it being used.

Answer (score 1):

1. An OPC UA Call Service Request need to contain an Array of `CallMethodRequest` 
   A CallMethod Request is defined as following in the OPC UA Specification:

   - **objectId** (*NodeId*) - The NodeId shall be that of the Object or ObjectType on which the Method is invoked. -> I guess this is your `QOpcUaNode`
   - **methodId** (*NodedId*) - The NodeId of the Method to invoke.
   - **inputArguments**[] (*BaseDataType*) - List of input argument values.
2. You will have to check your Method definition and maybe your server. Your call of `callMethod(methodId)` without arguments is fine. Depending of the Method you are calling, this call might succeed or not.

Anyway your OPC UA Server might also have an issue sending `Bad_TooManyArguments` instead of `Bad_ArgumentsMissing` if it was waiting for some inputArguments you did not provide.